# Can't create a .dll from Matlab Coder

Tags: c, matlab, dll, matlab-coder

I am trying to convert some matlab code into a c dynamic library (.dll) using the Matlab Coder tool. I'm trying it on some simple sample code, but I keep getting the same error which I can't find a solution to.

My code is:

```
function y = lbryTest(x, z) %#codegen
%QUICKTEST Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
y = 1.0;
a = x + z;
b = x * a;
y = b/3 + y;
end
```

I've tried using the app version of coder as well as the command:  `codegen -config:dll lbryTest -args {2.0, 5.0}`
and the build log, including the error, is:

```
1   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcc64 -c -w -noregistrylookup -nodeclspec -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/include64 -DMODEL=lbryTest -DHAVESTDIO -DUSE_RTMODEL -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB/codegen/dll/lbryTest -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/ert -Fo"lbryTest_initialize.obj" "lbryTest_initialize.c"
2   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcc64 -c -w -noregistrylookup -nodeclspec -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/include64 -DMODEL=lbryTest -DHAVESTDIO -DUSE_RTMODEL -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB/codegen/dll/lbryTest -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/ert -Fo"lbryTest_terminate.obj" "lbryTest_terminate.c"
3   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcc64 -c -w -noregistrylookup -nodeclspec -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/include64 -DMODEL=lbryTest -DHAVESTDIO -DUSE_RTMODEL -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB/codegen/dll/lbryTest -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/ert -Fo"lbryTest.obj" "lbryTest.c"
4   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcc64 -c -w -noregistrylookup -nodeclspec -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/include64 -DMODEL=lbryTest -DHAVESTDIO -DUSE_RTMODEL -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB/codegen/dll/lbryTest -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/ert -Fo"rt_nonfinite.obj" "rt_nonfinite.c"
5   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcc64 -c -w -noregistrylookup -nodeclspec -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/include64 -DMODEL=lbryTest -DHAVESTDIO -DUSE_RTMODEL -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB/codegen/dll/lbryTest -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/ert -Fo"rtGetNaN.obj" "rtGetNaN.c"
6   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcc64 -c -w -noregistrylookup -nodeclspec -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/include64 -DMODEL=lbryTest -DHAVESTDIO -DUSE_RTMODEL -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB -IC:/Users/shutchinson/Documents/MATLAB/codegen/dll/lbryTest -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/src/ext_mode/common -IC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/ert -Fo"rtGetInf.obj" "rtGetInf.c"
7   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/perl/win32/bin/perl.exe C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/rtw/c/tools/mkvc_lnk.pl lbryTest.lnk lbryTest_initialize.obj lbryTest_terminate.obj lbryTest.obj rt_nonfinite.obj rtGetNaN.obj rtGetInf.obj lccstub.obj
8   "### Creating dynamic library "./lbryTest.dll" ..."
9   C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/bin/lcclnk64 -dll -entry LibMain -s -LC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2015a/sys/lcc64/lcc64/lib64  lbryTest.def -o ./lbryTest.dll @lbryTest.lnk  
10   cannot open lccstub.obj
11   gmake: *** [lbryTest.dll] Error 1
12   The make command returned an error of 2
13   'An_error_occurred_during_the_call_to_make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
14   operable program or batch file.
15   
16   Error(s) encountered while building model "lbryTest":
17   ### Failed to generate all binary outputs.
```

I can make a .lib from this code, but I need a .dll, which is proving difficult. It looks like I am missing some object file or matlab can't find it, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: May be you should also post the command you used to generate the code.

Comment: Posting the entire build log may be helpful as well including the lines where the C files were compiled. Is the file lccstub.obj generated in the `codegen` directory, `codegen\dll\lbryTest` by default?

Comment: Another thing to check, does the full path to the codegen directory contain any "special" characters? Things like $, &, non-English characters have been known to cause issues with gmake. Contacting [MathWorks technical support](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/) may be helpful in this case.

Comment: I posted the build log, I don't have any weird characters in the path.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the file `lccstub.c` is not being compiled to produce `lccstub.obj` for some reason. For a quick workaround, you might consider installing another [supported compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/index.html). [This article](http://trweb.mathworks.com/tr/result?id=3654568978) describes installing and using the freely available Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 to use with MATLAB.

Comment: From what I can see there is no lccstub.c. I don't know why it wants there to be one. I'll look into your suggestion.

Comment: lccstub.c should ship with MATLAB. But I'd still recommend trying the Windows SDK for building shared libraries.

Comment: Installing the Windows SDK worked, thanks. Now to fix the next problem in the project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credit to Ryan Livingston for this suggestion, which I am turning into an official answer

The file lccstub.c (compiled to lccstub.obj) isn't on your machine, when it should be. To fix it, you should install a supported compiler for Matlab.

Windows SDK 7.1 is available for free from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/index.html?refresh=true)